# how to avoid trouble caused by duplicate picture name in php

Tags: php, mysql

All images are uploaded into image folder under my php project while reference goes into mysql table, but my confusion is, what if there are two images have the same name, are there better way to avoid duplicate naming happen? i know i cant control how will user naming their image file.

Comment: You could use the primary key of your column to generate a filename. Never use the user provided one.

Comment: or you can use timestamp as a the file name and save it into the image folder and also save the same into the db as a seperate column some thing like file_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security and yes to avoid duplicate you could change the `filename` to your own format,

example. formats
`$filename = sha1(time().$original_filename)` or `$filename = md5(time().$originalfilename)` it is up to you.

One advantage of changing the filename is that if an attacker uploads something, you are sure he will not find it because of a different name,other than the already security validations you have provided.

Comment: sha1 and md5 does encryption right, so how about the reference in my mysql table, also same to $filename? bc i cant think of any other haha

Comment: no, it just hashes the strings you provided, hash and encryption is different, but it better to go with `sha1` to avoid collisions as `md5` has a bigger rate of collision.You have to change just the filename.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do a combination of timestamp and a big random value (just in case):

So for example:

```
$filename = time() . rand(1000000,9999999) . strtolower($ext);
```

Where $ext is the extension (whether it's jpg, png or whatever).

This is also more secure than accepting filenames from user.

And the reason for strtolower, is because sometimes someone will upload something like IMAGE.JPG, so rather on counting that your server and all your scripts will be case insensitive, you can simply make sure that all extensions are in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Like VMai said before. Primary key is a good solution. But if You just wan`t to know solution with same name problem:

```
$filename = 'myfilename'; // without extension!
$extension = '.jpg';
$dir = '/directory/';
$fullPath = $dir.$filename.$extension;
$i=1;
$newFilename = filename;
while(file_exists($fullPath))
{
    $newFilename = $filename.'_'.$i;
    $i++;
    $fullPath = $dir.$newFilename.$extension;
}
```

Not tested, but You got the concept